# flask-migrate: running custom SQL in migrations?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I need to run some custom SQL on my table before applying a migration. In particular, I need to populate a column before declaring it non-nullable:

```
Clickid.query\
        .filter(Clickid.first_seen_at == None)\
        .update({'first_seen_at': datetime.utcnow()})
```

I've read about `op.execute` method in Alembic docs, where we feed raw SQL to the `execute` method:

```
op.execute(
    account.update().\
        where(account.c.name==op.inline_literal('account 1')).\
        values({'name':op.inline_literal('account 2')})
        )
```

however, with `Flask-SQLALchemy` my query does not return a string with SQL, it runs the SQL itself, returning number of rows modified:

```
print(Clickid.query
          .filter(Clickid.first_seen_at == None)
          .update({'first_seen_at': datetime.utcnow()})
          )
>>> 150
```

how do I make this work properly?

Comment: If I am correct, you are trying to prepopulate a column `first_seen_at` with current timestamp.
Can you check whether this is reflected in the table?

Comment: yes it is reflected in the table, after I issue a `db.session.commit()`of course.